# HTTP PUT in angular not working properly, but no error code

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http, put

I have a class like this:

```
id: any;

phonenumber: PhoneNumberInterface;

httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
})};

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getPhoneNumber(this.id).subscribe(phonenumber => this.phonenumber = phonenumber);
}

updatePhoneNumber(phonenumber: PhoneNumberInterface): Observable<any> {
    console.log('updatePhoneNumber is called');
    phonenumber.phoneNumberType = 'BLOCKED';
    console.log(phonenumber);
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/phonenumbers/${this.id}`;

    return this.httpClient.put(url, phonenumber, this.httpOptions).pipe();
}

getPhoneNumber(id: number): Observable<PhoneNumberInterface> {
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/phonenumbersmanagement/api/v1/phonenumbers/${id}`;

    return this.httpClient.get<PhoneNumberInterface>(url).pipe();
}
```

The update happens when I click on a button:

```
<button (click)="updatePhoneNumber((phonenumber))">Manuell sperren</button>
```

The focus lies on **updatePhoneNumber()**.

I am trying to update a phonenumber, which is a big object in my rest application. Before I am using the put()-method, I am print the "phonenumber" variable to the console. It is perfectly fine, but nothing happens. The object doesn't get updated. And I also don't receive any error code. Does anybody know why?

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: add the code where you are updating the phone number, looks like you are not subscribing to the result. and what are the empty pipes for, they do nothing.

Comment: Subscribing to the result? Could you please explain?

Comment: Check my answer, and remove the useless .pipe() code blocks

Comment: and accept it if it helped you, it was pretty obvious this was the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do anything:

```
 return this.httpClient.put(url, phonenumber, this.httpOptions).pipe();
```

As I said in the comment, you need to subscribe to the observable in order for the http request to get executed (like you did in ngOnInit).

```
 return this.httpClient.put(url, phonenumber, this.httpOptions).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Even tho this answer is correct, the `you need to subscribe to the observable in order for it to evaluate the result` part is wrong. If he doesn't subscribe the http won't get called. Hence nothing to evaluate.

Comment: true, that's what i meant. fixed it